# call azure management rest api through 'client credential' flow

Tags: azure, azure-rest-api, azure-rbac

I want to call some Azure management api, such as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/role-assignments/create?tabs=HTTP#security

but in docs, they mention just 'implicit grant' oauth2 flow.

I want to use 'client credential' (with registered apps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call **Azure Management REST API** using access token generated via client credentials flow.

Register one Azure AD application and add **API permissions** as below:

[image]

> Make sure to add **proper RBAC role** to above service principal before generating token.

In my case, I assigned **`User Access Administrator`** role to the service principal under subscription like below:

[image]

Now, I generated access token using **client credentials** flow via Postman like this:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:<appID>
client_secret:<secret>
scope: https://management.azure.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to call Azure Management REST API, I got **response** successfully like below:

```json
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subID>/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/<randomGUID>?api-version=2022-04-01

{
  "properties": {
    "roleDefinitionId": "/subscriptions/<subID>/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/<roledefId>",
    "principalId": "userId",
    "principalType": "User"
  }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. I got the point. 
But I cant see my service princiapl in list of members to choose. so, I created a security group, I add my application to it, I saw the group in rbac, and I added user admin role to it!